# Range to histogram

Tags: r, histogram, frequency

I'm trying to build a `histogram` from my data. It's look like this: a `data frame` where in each row a data range. I need to get the histogram of all values in my `df`.

```
year <- c("1925:2002",
          "2008",
          "1925:2002",
          "1925:2002",
          "1925:2002",
          "2008:2013",
          "1934",
          "1972:1988")
```

All I was able to figure out is to convert every string to a sequence with `seq()` but it doesn't work properly

```
for (i in 1:length(year)) {
  rr[i] <- seq(
    as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(year[i], ":"))[1]),
    as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(year[i], ":"))[2])
  )
}
```

Here is an example[image: base histogram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tick the answer box for @MrFlick. I had done this at the same time and the only difference is the piping:

```
library(magrittr)

strsplit(year, ":") %>% 
  lapply(as.integer) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) seq(x[1], x[length(x)])) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  hist()
```

Full-on `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

str_split(year, ":") %>%
  map(as.integer) %>% 
  map(~seq(.x[1], .x[length(.x)])) %>% 
  flatten_int() %>% 
  hist()
```

To defend my comments hence any `tidyverse` 4eva folks join in the fray:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  base = as.integer(
    unlist(
      lapply(
        lapply(
          strsplit(year, ":"),
          as.integer
        ),
        function(x) seq(x[1], x[length(x)])
      ),
      use.names = FALSE
    )
  ),
  tidy = str_split(year, ":") %>%
    map(as.integer) %>% 
    map(~seq(.x[1], .x[length(.x)])) %>% 
    flatten_int()
)
## Unit: microseconds
##  expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##  base  89.099  96.699 132.1684 102.5895 110.7165 2895.428   100
##  tidy 631.817 647.812 672.5904 667.8250 686.2740  909.531   100
```

Comment: Or maybe even prettier with `purrr`: `year %>% strsplit(":") %>% map(as.numeric) %>% map(~seq(head(.,1), tail(.,1))) %>% unlist()`

Comment: aye. I'm trying to wean off of the tidyverse a bit. Pretty hefty dependencies that often end up slowing down ops. I'll amend it tho for that.

Comment: using `length()` as an index hack now :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to split your years up.

```
years <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(year, ":"), function(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  if (length(x)==2) {
    return(seq(x[1], x[2]))
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}))
hist(years)
```

First we do the splitting, then we either expand it as a sequence or return the numeric value, and finally we `unlist()` everything to get a simple vector back.

[image]